# Use Underscore to transform/wrap an entire object into a new object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Underscore has mapping for arrays and functions, *but they work on the individual items*, not the entire thing.

So suppose I want to change an object's "shape" while chaining:

```
var result = _.chain(foo)
  .pluck(...)
  .stuff()
  .moreStuff()
  .TRANSFORMHERE()     // <------ what step/steps here to wrap the object? 
  .evenMoreStuff()
  .value();
```

So something like:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
```

to

```
{ foo: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}, bar: "hello" }
```

Without chaining it's easy. But what steps can I take while chaining, to take an object and wrap it as a property within a new object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone has a better/easier/builtin way, I guess we can [add a function to underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin):

```
_.mixin({
  wrapObject: function(obj, name) {
    var outer = {};
    outer[name] = obj;
    return outer;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`tap`](http://underscorejs.org/#tap).

```
var result = _.chain(foo)
  .pluck(...)
  .stuff()
  .moreStuff()
  .tap(function(obj) {
      obj.foo = { a : obj.a, b : obj.b, c : obj.c, d : obj.d };
      obj.bar = "hello";

      // Delete old keys
      delete obj.a;
      delete obj.b;
      delete obj.c;
      delete obj.d;
  })
  .evenMoreStuff()
  .value();
```

Not that you can't do something like this :

```
tap(function(obj) {
    return {
        a : obj.a,
        ...
        bar : "hello"
    };
});
```

The result of `tap` is ignored by underscore. So you have to modify the object directly.

Comment: That looks like it works... but, it's a "manual" process. Is there no underscore-style automated way to do it? What if there are dozens of properties, then this becomes painful, and you rather do it without chaining.

Comment: underscore.js does not have a function to transform object properties directly. Try to take a look at lodash (an extension of underscore), maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: So to the best of your knowledge, the answer is "it cannot be done"?

Comment: As far as i know, not in only one line or with a multi step automated way. But maybe someone will find a better way.